# Matlab select Graphics Hardware Acceleration

Tags: matlab, opengl, graphics, driver

Somehow the OpenGL renderer of my matlab (2010b) does not work correctly, meaning, the plots are weird compositions of patches instead of the smooth surface I actually generate. When changing the renderer to zbuffer it works fine, however, I miss the possibility to use transparency. Moreover, I get the feeling that using opengl I would experience a performance boost, such that rotating and zooming and stuff would happen quicker.

I think the reason lies in my computer hardware. I got an intel HD graphics 4600 plus a NIVIDIA Quadro K610M/PCIe/SSE2. When typing "opengl info" , that second graphics card is listed. I already updated the driver but nothing changed.

Any Ideas what may be the problem?

Own solution idea: I would like to test the Intel HD graphics but didnt find a way to set it as the default accelerator when running Matlab. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

***To switch the hardware used***:- You can choose the hardware support in NVIDIA control panel, as shown below in the link.

[image: Changing the graphics processor for MATLAB]

Restart MATLAB and check using "opengl info" command. The 'Vendor' should have switched to the integrated processor type.

Answer (score 0):

To get your smooth surfaces, you can run

```
opengl software
```

upon starting matlab. This doesn't solve your problem (I cannot run opengl hardware on my 64bit ubuntu HD4400 graphics), but might be a good workaround for the moment. 
Also this way you know it is the opengl, not something else.

No idea about how to switch the chosen graphics card though, sorry.